# Writing django queries

Tags: django, django-models

I am new to django world and i am trying to run below sql query on django .
    Any clue on how to write below equivalent query in django is much appreciated .

Model:

```
class UserTraining(models.Model):
    Training = models.CharField(max_length = 100,unique=True)
    Category = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    Due_date = models.DateField(default=None)

    def __str__ (self):
        return self.Training + " " + self.Category


class UserSummary(models.Model):
    Users = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)    
    Status = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    Duedate = models.DateField(default=None)
    CompletedDate = models.DateField(default=None)
    Hours = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Trainings = models.ForeignKey(UserTraining,to_field='Training',blank=False,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.Status

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    user_category = models.CharField(max_length = 100, blank=True, null=True)
    mobile = models.CharField(max_length=256, blank=True, null=True)
    DOJ = models.DateField(default=None)


    def __str__(self):
        return  self.user.first_name + " " + self.user_category
```

Working sql Query:

```
Select UT. Training , ifnull (US.Status ,'Pending')
from SkillTracker_usertraining UT 
     Left outer join SkillTracker_usersummary US
         On US.Trainings_id=UT.Training and Us.Users_id='4'
where UT.Category='EMEIA'
```

Need help in writing above sql query in django.

My objective behind this is to get user training status for all of his category if he has not yet attended training it should be displayed as pending.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
UserTraining.objects.filter(
    usersummary__Users__id=4
    ).values('Training', 'usersummary__Status')
```

where `usersummary` it is lowcase of `UserSummary` model class name, and i don't add `ifnull` because your status is not null field. Double underscore used for related objects or special condition like `__gt` or `__in` etc.

please read [django coding-style](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/), your code is not good for other developers

Comment: I am new to development world sure i will go through coding style. I have tried same but the response of that query is status for the training which user has attended. Suppose there are 3 trainings for EMEIA category and user is also from EMEIA then he has to attend 3 training but if he has only attended 2 out of 3 then in case of above query status for 3rd training wont be displayed. But i want that 3rd result to be displayed as pending since user has not yet attended.